# C++: using < bitset > to convert 01 string with unknown length into binary

Tags: c++

I am using Huffman to compress files, but was so suprised to find that the size of the compressed file is even larger than the original one ! After checking my code, I guess it may because the usage of bitset. Here is my code:

```
void Huffman::compression(string filename,string comfile)
{
    ofstream write(comfile, ios::binary);
    ifstream ts;
    ts.open(filename);
    string str,bitstr;
    while (getline(ts, str))
    {
        bitstr = to_bitstr(str);
        //to_bitstr() function convert string into 01 string
        stringstream ss(bitstr);
        while (ss.good())
        {
            bitset<8> bits;
            ss >> bits;
            write << bits;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested my program while using `bitset<16>` and `bitset<32>` respectively, and ,of course, the file is becoming larger and larger. I probably know reason: when the 01 bits cannot fill the size of bitset, it will be automatically filled, which may cost extra space.
I have been searching for a proper solution for quite a long time...
Here are my questions: **How to use < bitset > to convert a 01 string with unknown length into binary? Or is it impossible to do that? Is there any other better solution?**
I will be very grateful if you can tell me the answer !

Comment: You may use `std::bitset<8>` and break up the string in portions of 8 digits. The result will fit into a single byte of a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: How about [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)? `std::vector<>` is specialized for `bool` to store values as bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read the text as a string and convert it into 01 string and then  convert it into bitset. but i try fwrite instead, and it solve the problem.! your answer has gave me inspiration!

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is cool...

Answer (score 0):

### Easy solution

If performance is not a concern, `std::vector<bool>` is a good fit. It also doesn't support some library concepts, but it doesn't seem like you're using them anyway. It might require overloading of `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

### Harder solution

Roll your own. This will take some development time, but if you're not overgeneralizing, it should be pretty quick. Just test it before deployment.

### Taking dependency

Boost has dynamic bitset. I believe they have their own license, so it might take some time to figure out if it fits your project, but otherwise it is pretty well tested. I've used it myself, and it landed itself pretty nicely.

Comment: I have no idea about how to write `std::vector<bool>` to the binary file...I have tried several methods, but they just couldn't work. Is there any way to do this?